# Link certain files from Sharepoint Online to company's intranet

Tags: sharepoint-online, hyperlink, access

We are using SharePoint Online for team collaboration on a project.

A **subsite**/**library** under my company's account has been created for that. I cannot edit the overall public site as it is managed globally and not for our usage.

I do need to link certain files in the SharePoint to my company's intranet, so everyone in the company is able to access them. I can only find how to give access to certain people by their email addresses/names, but not how to create a link accessible in general.

Is there any solution for that?

Comment: links are just redirections or path to the original content. You cannot have permission based on url, atleast OOTB. The target file should have permission assigned to the users, then only links will be helpful

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think that phrases my problem a different way: I know how to give access to certain users. What I want to do is to create a link to a file on the SharePoint I can put on my company's intranet. I cannot assign permission to every single person as it is hundreds of people I want that file to be accessible to. If I just put the link available opening the file in SharePoint only project team members will be able to access it.

Comment: You can assign/give permission to NT Authority/Authenticated Users. this will allow all users under AD to have direct permissions

Comment: I do not understand exactly what you mean, can you explain further? What do you mean by NT and AD? How can I do it?

Comment: there is a special group NT Authority/Authenticated Users which represents all users from Active Directory. Just like a normal user id, when you assign permissions to a site/list/file you add users id, similar way instead of a user id, you have to add 'NT Authority/Authenticated Users'. This will provide permissions to all users from Active directory of your company. Then display the links as you want.

Comment: in simpler way. If you have a SP group which have read/write permissions to those files/folders, just add this user 'NT Authority/Authenticated Users' to that group and you are done with assigning permission to all users in a go

Comment: sorry .. It works fine in On Premise SP. For Online type 'All' in people picker while adding to the SPGroup, as mentioned Above. It will provide you  suggestions

Comment: Thanks! It is giving me suggestions, but to me it looks like I would send an invitation to everyone this way? However, the "Get a link" option seems to work fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allow external sharing in SharePoint Online site collection - if you cannot do that, you're out of luck.

However, if external sharing has been enabled or you can enable it, go to document you wish to share, select Share. Then choose "Get a link", and from drop-down select "View link - no sign-in required". Then copy&paste the link to your company intranet.

Comment: Thanks! The "Get a link" method seems to work fine, I did not spot it previously. Thank you so much! However, the file opens in Excel Online by clicking the link by default, and some features are not supported in the browser version. Even if the user decides to download it from there these features are disabled in the downloaded version as well. Is there an option to have the file opening in Excel right away by default?